# Get a list of tweets with javascript

Tags: jquery, twitter

Is it possible to retrieve a users tweets using a jQuery AJAX request? I have the following code but I'm getting the same origin error.

```
function GetTweets(handle) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=wesleyskeen"
    }).success(function (tweets) { 
        console.log(tweets) 
    });
}
```

Even when I add

```
dataType: "jsonp"
```

I get a different error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

The results are actually returned, but they are returned in XML as it seems to be giving the script a problem.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: If it's XML that is returned, and the API does not support cross-domain requests, you'll have to do this on the serverside, using your webserver as a proxy of sorts. Something tells me twitter has a solution for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are requesting XML. Uso the json url instead:

https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=wesleyskeen

(Simply change **xml** in your url **path**  to json)

Comment: This does not appear to work any more getting a 410 error with that link